# Invoke-WebRequest All Elements

Tags: powershell

I am using the `Invoke-WebRequest` function in Powershell and am grabbing this

```
$WebResponse = Invoke-WebRequest $siteExt
$WebResponse.AllElements | ? { $_.Class -eq 'price' } | select innerText
```

When I print it out however, it give me every single element - like the .AllElements implies. However, lets say it is printing out 5 prices and I want to specifically grab, store and output one of those positions- lets say every 3rd value. Is there a way to do that?

It prints out this currently:

```
innerText
---------
$31.00   
$72.00   
$209.95
```

I just want the first value though; not all 3. I also would like to store it in a list.

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler those do not apply to the way Invoke `WebRequest` function- I believe. I know how to count, store variables and iterate through them. However, when I am actively capturing the information through the `WebRequest` function I do not know how to apply those concepts in relation to it. My question is how can I select just one of the "all elements" that are returned.

Comment: "*those do not apply to the way Invoke WebRequest function- I believe*" - why do you believe that? You *must* believe they work, you use both filtering and selecting in your own code right there in your question and you think it works there.. Once you get objects output into a pipeline, it makes no difference where they came from.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this.
Just the first:

```
$WebResponse.AllElements|?{$_.Class -eq 'price'}|select innerText | select -first 1
```

Every third:

```
$WebResponse.AllElements | ?{$_.Class -eq 'price'} | select innerText | select -index ((1..$WebResponse.AllElements.Count)| % {$p=$_;if(($_ %= 3) -eq 2){[string]$p+","}})
```

-

Comment: Brilliant! I was unable to find how to do that. Thank you my good sir!

Comment: Any idea how I could store that value into a list? :)

Comment: Yes... That's your homework. Don't forget to analyze the crap out of it so you can come up with a better version ;)

Comment: . . . I respect that xD. I just learned it most definitely is NOT `$price = $WebResponse` lol. Back to the drawing board. Thanks!